# Data decorated with [DataMember] is not being validated during deserialization in Asp.Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a DTO class like

```
[DataContract]
public class MyDTO
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired)]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

When I make a `POST` request without `MyProperty`, I do not get any exception.

EDIT:

My controller looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromForm] MyDTO newDTO)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var errors = this.GetModelStateErrors();
        return this.BadRequest();
    }

    try
    {
        var newDo = this.mapper.Map<MYDTO, MyDO>(newDto);
        await this.dataManager.InsertAsync(this.myDbContext, newDo);

        return this.StatusCode(201);
    }
    catch (ValidationException e)
    {
        return this.BadRequest(e.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return this.StatusCode(500, "Unspecified error occurred while processing request.");
    }
}
```

I'm doing validation on the DO in the Db Context as well. I would like to validate the DTO.

Comment: Can you share the code of API? Did you write any validation in the API?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Added my controller.

Comment: You should not be using `DataMember` and `DataContract` for the web API model validations. You should be using classes available in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace. Also `[FromForm]` is not for WebAPI.  Read [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) to understand the validation in Web API.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyDTO
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i encountered the same 'issue', let me explain my understanding:

`DataContract` and `DataMember` are inside the *System.Runtime.Serialization* namespace.
Which means they are related to **serialization** behavior
They are not meant to be used for model validation.
The `IsRequired` information indicates to the serializer if the field must be present in the serialized message.

If you need to validate if the **data** stored in a field must be validated, you must use attributes from *System.ComponentModel.**Data**Annotations*
Attributes in this namespace are meant for **Data** validation